# AWS: aws ssm describe-available-patches reutruns nothing for RedhatEnterpriseLinux7

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I'm trying to define a PatchBaseline for instances running RHEL7. So I run the following command to check available patches.

```sh
aws ssm --region eu-central-1 describe-available-patches --filters Key=PRODUCT,Values=RedhatEnterpriseLinux7
```

It returns an empty list:

```json
{
    "Patches": []
}
```

Also tried other OS names including RedhatEnterpriseLinux7.x and RedhatEnterpriseLinux8, from `describe-patch-properties`.

None of them have any available patches.

I'm not sure if I have done something wrong, or this is the intended behavior?

Comment: Are these monitored instances with the SSM agent installed, plus do they have the appropriate permissions to communicate with the SSM service?

Comment: @Norman yes, they do. They show up in the fleet manager normally. And also, this should have nothing to do with the instances. The API should return all supported patches for RHEL7 regardless of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your product value is invalid.

For example, you can try running the following for AmazonLinux2.0.

```
aws ssm --region eu-central-1 describe-available-patches --filters Key=PRODUCT,Values=AmazonLinux2.0 --max-items 2
```

You can see the available products from console. For example,
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, indeed, AmazonLinux2 works fine. The problem is they refuse to work with REDHAT linux. The product value are retrieved with the command `aws --region eu-central-1 ssm describe-patch-properties --operating-system REDHAT_ENTERPRISE_LINUX --property PRODUCT` so I'm pretty sure they are valid.